# Old ringtones from android 1.0?

Tags: htc-desire, 1.5-cupcake, ringtone

I had a Android Dev G1 phone (which has long since bitten the dust). it was running android 1.0 (later updated to 1.5). I have just gotten a HTC Desire running 2.2. There was a nice ringtone on the 1.0 that i'd like to get again. Is there anyway to download the ld ringtones that were on 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

My Android 1.6 phone has the following files in the /system/media/audio/ringtones directory. Are any of these the one you want?

```
Noises2.ogg
BirdLoop.ogg
Noises1.ogg
Big_Easy.ogg
No_Limits.ogg
BentleyDubs.ogg
NewPlayer.ogg
BeatPlucker.ogg
World.ogg
MildlyAlarming.ogg
VeryAlarmed.ogg
MidEvilJaunt.ogg
TwirlAway.ogg
LoveFlute.ogg
Thunderfoot.ogg
LoopyLounge.ogg
Third_Eye.ogg
InsertCoin.ogg
Terminated.ogg
Growl.ogg
Steppin_Out.ogg
Glacial_Groove.ogg
SpringyJalopy.ogg
Gimme_Mo_Town.ogg
SitarVsSitar.ogg
GameOverGuitar.ogg
Shes_All_That.ogg
Funk_Yall.ogg
Seville.ogg
FriendlyGhost.ogg
Savannah.ogg
EtherShake.ogg
RomancingTheTone.ogg
Eastern_Sky.ogg
Road_Trip.ogg
DreamTheme.ogg
Ring_Synth_04.ogg
CurveBall.ogg
Ring_Synth_02.ogg
CrazyDream.ogg
Ring_Digital_02.ogg
Club_Cubano.ogg
Ring_Classic_02.ogg
Champagne_Edition.ogg
Revelation.ogg
CaribbeanIce.ogg
Paradise_Island.ogg
Calypso_Steel.ogg
OrganDub.ogg
Cairo.ogg
Noises3.ogg
Bollywood.ogg
```

Comment: I can't remember the name of the ringtone. However I think it was a jungle type, upbeat, 'happy' sound. I think it might have been the default ringtone in 1.0